# Найдено на стоянке или в стоянке (археология)

Tags: предлоги

Подскажите, пожалуйста, если имеется в виду стоянка как археологический термин (поселения древних), то употребляется предлог "на" или "в"?

Answer (score 2):

Как правило, археологи предлог не меняют, *на стоянке, на раскопках, в поселении, в городище*.

Answer (score 0):

Марку Изу, конечно, виднее, как более близкому к вопросу, но я не совсем уверен, что здесь уместно объединение двух значений слова "стоянка".

Такое ощущение со стороны, что профессионалы используют оба предлога - в зависимости от смысла. "На стоянке" - это про место, география, грубо говоря.  А "в стоянке" - это в отношении совокупности материальных свидетельств.

Могу фантазировать, имхо глубокое.